# gradient function that treats nan values like edges

Tags: python, numpy

I am looking for a function like numpy.gradient, which has a built-in treatment for NaN values. It should recognize where a NaN value occurs and compute one-sided derivatives at those points.

For example if f[x-epx], f[x], and f[x+epx] are all not NaN, I would like it to calculate a derivative like:

```
grad_f[x] = (f[x+epx] - f[x-epx])/(2*eps)
```

however, if f[x-eps] is Nan then I would like to obtain the following derivative:

```
grad_f[x] = (f[x+eps] - f[x])/eps
```

I am looking for a function that does this also in higher dimensions. Do you know any such function?
Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I had quite a similar problem. Imagine a 3D volume that contains nan values almost everywhere except at the center where the 3D object of interest is. When deriving the  3D volume with numpy.gradient the outmost layer of the object is lost, you end up with nan values at the interface whereas you had values before.

So here a piece of code that computes the second order gradient within the object (in the interior) but compute the first order gradient at the boundaries :

```
def hybrid_gradient(data, dx, dy, dz):
    """
    Compute the gradient of a 3D volume in the 3 directions, 2 nd order 
    in the interior of the non-nan object, 1 st order at the interface between
    the non-nan object and the surrounding nan values.

    :param data: the 3D volume to be derived (3D np.ndarray)
    :param dx: the spacing in the x direction (axis 0)
    :param dy: the spacing in the y direction (axis 1)
    :param dz: the spacing in the z direction (axis 2)

    :return: a tuple, the three gradients (in each direction) with the
    same shape as the input data
    """

    grad_x = (data[1:, ...] - data[:-1, ...]) / dx
    grad_y = (data[:, 1:, :] - data[:, :-1, :]) / dy
    grad_z = (data[..., 1:] - data[..., :-1]) / dz
    
    grad_x = np.nanmean([grad_x[1:], grad_x[:-1]], axis=0)
    grad_y = np.nanmean([grad_y[: ,1:, :], grad_y[:, :-1, :]], axis=0)
    grad_z = np.nanmean([grad_z[..., 1:], grad_z[..., :-1]], axis=0)


    return (
        np.pad(grad_x, ((1, 1),  (0, 0), (0, 0)), constant_values=np.nan),
        np.pad(grad_y, ((0, 0),  (1, 1), (0, 0)), constant_values=np.nan),
        np.pad(grad_z, ((0, 0),  (0, 0), (1, 1)), constant_values=np.nan)
    )
```

Some short explanations:

- Consider a 1d basic example with:

```
array = np.array([np.nan, np.nan, 1, 2, 5, 6, 8, np. nan, np.nan, np.nan])
```

- The first code block of the function computes a first order gradient (note that nan - nan = nan and nan - non_nan = nan). We have:

```
>>> first_order_array = array[1:] - array[:-1] / 1 # say our constant sample distance is 1
>>> first_order_array
array([nan, nan,  1.,  3.,  1.,  2., nan, nan, nan])
```

- The second code block is the tricky one. Using the numpy.nanmean allows keeping the values we need (the mean of nan and non_nan is non_nan !) See here:

```
>>> grad_array = np.nanmean([first_order_array[1:], first_order_array[:-1]], axis=0)
<stdin>:1: RuntimeWarning: Mean of empty slice
>>> grad_array
array([nan, 1. , 2. , 2. , 1.5, 2. , nan, nan])
```

The mean values that are in the interior of the object corresponds to second order gradient. At the boundaries we still have the one order gradient.

- Finally, as we kind of cropped our data we must pad them (if the final output shape is required to be the same as the input one)

```
>>> padded_grad_array = np.pad(grad_array, (1, 1), constant_values=np.nan)
>>> padded_grad_array
array([nan, nan, 1. , 2. , 2. , 1.5, 2. , nan, nan, nan])
```

- Let's compare with numpy:

```
>>> np.gradient(array)
array([nan, nan, nan, 2. , 2. , 1.5, nan, nan, nan, nan])
>>> padded_grad_array
array([nan, nan, 1. , 2. , 2. , 1.5, 2. , nan, nan, nan])
```

We have two more values (at the interface), the number of nan values should be the same before and after the gradient.

Caution: This only works with "ideal" data. If you have sequence of nan and non-nan values it may be different.
Also note the `RunTimeWarning` when doing the mean of empty slices.

Comment: How would you adapt this code to work for two dimensions? I tried deleting everything pertaining to the z axis but with a sample array A = np.array([ [1, 2, 3], [2, 5, 6], [6, 18, np.nan] ]) I got that the gradient arrays only have one column/row of non-nans, which is not good.